# DirectX not detecting all graphics cards

Tags: c++, directx, video-card

I'm having problem detecting some graphics cards using DirectX API. The code I wrote looks like following:

```cpp
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <Dxgi1_6.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

struct AdapterInfo
{
    std::wstring description;
    size_t vRam;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL maxFeatureLevel;
};

void getGPUDescriptionVideoRam(IUnknown* pDevice, AdapterInfo & adapterInfo)
{
    CComPtr<IDXGIDevice> pDXGIDevice;
    pDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&pDXGIDevice);

    if (pDXGIDevice)
    {
        CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> pDXGIAdapter;
        pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&pDXGIAdapter);

        if (pDXGIAdapter != nullptr)
        {
            DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
            pDXGIAdapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);

            adapterInfo.description = std::wstring(adapterDesc.Description);
            adapterInfo.vRam = adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory;
        }
    }
}

std::vector<AdapterInfo> GetDescriptionVRamDirectx()
{
    std::vector<AdapterInfo> result;

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[10] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_1_0_CORE
    };

    CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> higher_performance_adapter;
    CComPtr<IDXGIFactory> pFactory;
    HRESULT createDXGIFactoryResult = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)(&pFactory));

    if (createDXGIFactoryResult != S_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to create DXGI factory!\n");
        return result;
    }

    printf("Trying to enumerate graphics adapters...\n");

    int i = 0;
    while (pFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &higher_performance_adapter) == S_OK)
    /*
    while (pFactory->EnumAdapterByGpuPreference(i,
        DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_UNSPECIFIED,
        __uuidof(IDXGIAdapter),
        (void**)&higher_performance_adapter) == S_OK)
    */
    {
        i++;

        CComPtr<ID3D11Device> device = nullptr;
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL receivedFeatureLevel;
        CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context = nullptr;

        const HRESULT err = D3D11CreateDevice(
            higher_performance_adapter,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
            nullptr,
            0, // D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG
            featureLevels,
            1,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &device,
            &receivedFeatureLevel,
            &context);

        if (err != S_OK)
        {
            higher_performance_adapter = nullptr;
            continue;
        }

        AdapterInfo info;
        getGPUDescriptionVideoRam(device, info);
        info.maxFeatureLevel = receivedFeatureLevel;

        result.push_back(info);       

        higher_performance_adapter = CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter>();
    }

    return result;
}

void displayWMIAdapters()
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        return;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
        NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
        0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
        NULL,                    // Security flags.
        0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
        0,                       // Context object 
        &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return;                // Program has failed.
    }

    std::cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << std::endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_VideoController"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        std::cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        std::wcout << " OS Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << std::endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto adapters = GetDescriptionVRamDirectx();

    int i = 1;
    for (AdapterInfo adapter : adapters)
    {
        printf("Adapter %d:\n", i);
        printf("-----------\n");
        printf("Description      :");
        wprintf(adapter.description.c_str());
        printf("\n");
        printf("Video RAM        :");
        wprintf(L"%d", adapter.vRam);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Feature level    :");

        if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1)
            printf("12_1\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0)
            printf("12_0\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1)
            printf("11_1\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0)
            printf("11_0\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1)
            printf("10_1\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0)
            printf("10_0\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3)
            printf("9_3\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2)
            printf("9_2\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1)
            printf("9_1\n");
        else if (adapter.maxFeatureLevel == D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_1_0_CORE)
            printf("1_0_CORE\n");
        printf("\n");      

        i++;
    }

    displayWMIAdapters();

    printf("Press any key...\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Note, that I'm also using WMI to enumerate graphics cards.
So on most devices this works correctly, namely:

```
Trying to enumerate graphics adapters...
Adapter 1:
-----------
Description      :NVIDIA GeForce MX250
Video RAM        :2080038912
Feature level    :12_1

Adapter 2:
-----------
Description      :Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
Video RAM        :134217728
Feature level    :12_1

Adapter 3:
-----------
Description      :Microsoft Basic Render Driver
Video RAM        :0
Feature level    :12_1

Connected to ROOT\CIMV2 WMI namespace
 OS Name : Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
 OS Name : NVIDIA GeForce MX250
Press any key...
```

However, I'm getting information, that on specific setups, no results are returned. For instance my friend said,

> My notebook (not all information, installed graphics cards are 2xGT755m in SLI plus standard, integrated - 3 in total)

```
Adapter 1:
-----------
Description      :Microsoft Basic Render Driver
Video RAM        :0
Feature level    :12_1

Press any key...
```

I'm having trouble finding out, why I am not getting all cards. Moreover, I have no idea, what kind of debugging could I perform to find out the reason of my problem.

Why am I not getting all installed graphics cards on all machines when using DirectX API?

Comment: Does DxDiag works ok on these setups where your code fails? If your code is representative, you should add error checking to get error numbers too. Also, you shouldn't need to ask for D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0 and D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_1 if you just need adapter names. As for WMI, you can also use `wmic path win32_VideoController get name` on the setups to check what it gives back.

Comment: You may want to look at this [VideoMemory](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/VideoMemory) sample.

Comment: There is an array of 10 items `featureLevels`, however when `D3D11CreateDevice` is invoked 1 is supplied as an amount of items in this array so only the highest feature level is checked.

Comment: @user7860670, this is most likely the case, I'll check that out. Thanks!